# PHP date causing XML error

Tags: php

Using PHP Version 5.2.13, I'm trying to use the date() function to get/format date, 
such function is causing me to get all page in blank and firebug is showing the following error (XML tab):

XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{e80b3b2e-b8f1-4a2d-b906-03d42ca6a190} Line Number 1, Column 1:

^

```
<td class="darkBlueTD">
                <?php echo date("d");?>
            </td>
```

Comment: Need more detail.  I can almost guarantee it's not date()'s fault -- though the way you're using it could be wrong.  Why not post some code and explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks timdev!! I just need to add the line date("d"); to get the error, If I delete the line I get the page working :(

Answer (score 1):

That's just Firefox's way of telling you that there was absolutely no content on the page. Your script isn't outputting anything for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any custom error reporting? PHP (since 5.1.0) issues the E_STRICT and E_NOTICE time zone errors.

What I mean is that PHP might issue the "It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings." warning and if your error handler is designed to halt on every error, it might be the cause of your sript not outputting any content.